# fill JQuery progress bar with 'hidden' html value issue

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

Good day every one.
I have a JQuery's progress Bar in my jsp page and I want to fill it with the value dynamically. to full fill this requirement I have added a 'hidden' HTML form element in my page with name="budgetProgress" which points out to a variable of the Action class and when I try to use that value to fill the progress bar it is not happening. Below is my code.

```
<body>
<h3 align="center">DashBoard</h3>
 <form action="progressBar">
   <tags:hidden name="budgetProgress" value="50" class="hiddenProgres"></tags:hidden>
</form>
<div id="progressbar"></div>

<script src="jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
 var progresVal=$("input[name='budgetProgress']").val();
$("#progressbar").width(300);
$("#progressbar").height(25);
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: progresVal
 });
</script>
</body>
```

Here is my dashboard image which is fill with 0% of progress. To make it clearly visible I have coloured it with black.
   [image]

can some help me in achieving this. Let me know if any need any additional code/info to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use document ready parseInt your value

```
$(function(){
 var progresVal=$(".hiddenProgres").val();
$("#progressbar").width(300);
$("#progressbar").height(25);
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: parseInt(progresVal)
 });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uz5swvo5/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I have changed the code as per your suggestion, But no luck.